# I can't figure this out: SQL Server 2008: Error converting data type varchar to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddTimesheetStaffAvailability]
    (@staffid int,
     @TheDate datetime,
     @Workcode varchar(50))
AS
    INSERT INTO Timesheet (staffid, thedate, workcode)
    VALUES (@staffid, @TheDate, @Workcode)
GO
```

```
EXEC AddTimesheetStaffAvailability 
         @staffid = 7853,                     -- int
         @TheDate = '2022-08-02 01:40:21',    -- datetime
         @Workcode = 'iN'                     -- varchar(50)
```

This call works!

But:

```
EXEC AddTimesheetStaffAvailability 
        @staffid = 7853,                     -- int
        @TheDate = '2022-04-27 07:45:25',    -- datetime
        @Workcode = 'iN'                     -- varchar(50)
```

results in this error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 1, Procedure AddTimesheetStaffAvailability, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 25]
> Error converting data type varchar to datetime

Comment: See https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/166772/220697

Comment: thanks but the format of the two dates are identical, i don't see why one would work and the other would not.

Comment: It's probably interpreting it as `yyyy-dd-mm hh:mm:ss`, as it's not an unambiguous date format. There is no month #27, for clarity. Try `SELECT MONTH(CAST('2022-08-02 01:40:21' AS datetime))` and see whether you get `8` or `2`

Comment: For an unambiguous format, at least in SQL Server, try `yyyy-dd-mmThh:mm:ss`. The letter `T` is important. The date is probably getting parsed incorrectly because you appear to have `set dateformat dmy;` in effect.

Comment: SELECT MONTH(CAST('2022-08-02 01:40:21' AS datetime)) returns 2
SELECT MONTH(CAST('2022-04-27 01:40:21' AS datetime)) returns 'The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.'

I don't get this issue with SQL 2019 but you are correct, it is interpreting it as yyyy-dd-mm. Do you know if this can be changed at the server level?

Answer (score -1):

Did you checked your queries as the same queries are working for me and inserting records.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFrbB.png)

Comment: double checked, tipple checked.. what version of sql server are you running?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).